# Windows 7 - when running old games, rundll32 is started for the first time

Tags: windows-7, gaming, rundll32.exe

When I try to run some old games (specifically Diablo 2 now), when I double click the game icon, nothing happens, except for a Rundll32.exe starts under my current user, which consumes one of my CPU. I can get to the game by running it "again" - when I run the game for the second time, the game starts correctly, but runs slowly - the RunDLL process consumes another processor.

I have a workaround for this issue - it is possible to kill the Rundll32 process after actually running the game (=double clicking the icon twice) and it runs just fine. I am pretty sure this is not caused by a virus or a malware (computer protected by Eset Smart Security and Spybot). Any idea how to fix this issue so that it would be possible to run the game just once?

Comment: Have you tried to run it in [compatibility mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-older-programs-run#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: Simpler than I expected. Just for the record (if someone was looking for that), after running Diablo II in XP SP3 compatibility mode, I had to run the video test in compatibility mode as well, then the game works as expected. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Also see this related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1075848/why-does-windows-games-explorer-attempt-to-access-the-internet-whenever-i-laun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Windows 7 Compatibility Mode to "Make older programs run in this version of Windows".

> Most programs written for Windows Vista also work in this version of
>   Windows, but some older programs might run poorly or not at all. If a
>   program written for an earlier version of Windows doesn't run
>   correctly, you can try changing the compatibility settings for the
>   program, either manually or by using the Program Compatibility
>   troubleshooter.

Here is info how using [Compatibility Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-older-programs-run#1TC=windows-7).

Answer (score 8):

When you start any game installed in Windows, game explorer tries to go to
the Microsoft game update site:

https://games.metaservices.microsoft.com/games/SGamesWebService.asmx

If you do not have a working web connection, the `rundll` will hang.
To defeat the update check, open `regedit`, find this folder:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LocalSettings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\GameUX\ServiceLocation
```

You will see the games key. Rename the key. Right click the right pane and
create new string value called "Games". Double click the value and insert any local path on your computer (make it chase a dummy). Restart your computer.

Comment: this should be the accepted the answer, as the symptoms described in the question occur when game explorer tries to go to the Microsoft game update site.

Comment: It was "Local Settings" not "LocalSettings" for me in Win7. Fixed my problem.. pretty disgusting that